# About Aristotelian ἐπιχαιρεκακία

Tags: vocabulary, greek, aristotle

In [this passage](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0086,010:1107a:10&lang=original) from *Nicomachean Ethics*, Aristotle uses the word ἐπιχαιρεκακία to mean:

> [joy over one's neighbour's misfortune](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=e)pixairekaki/a)

My question is, Does ἐπιχαιρεκακία have a Latin counterpart in either Classical or Medieval ethical works?

Comment: The "English" equivalent of ἐπιχαιρεκακία is the loan word "Schadenfreude".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After brief research, it appears that Latin had no equivalent of ἐπιχαιρεκακία (i.e., a single word capturing the essence of the Greek word). Rather, Thomas Aquinas (for one) translated the word ἐπιχαιρεκακία into Latin as *gaudium de malo*,<sup>1</sup> which in English translates as “joy from evil (misfortune).”

In *Dictionarium Latino-Græcum*, a Latin-Greek dictionary composed by Charles Estienne in 1554, Estienne defined ἐπιχαιρεκακία as *gaudium ex alienis malis acceptum*—“joy received from another’s misfortune.”<sup>2</sup>

---

### References

Aquinas, Thomas. [*Commentary on the Nicomachean Ethics.*](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/Ethics.htm) Trans. Litzinger, C. I. Chicago: Regnery, 1964.

Estienne, Charles. [*Dictionarium Latino-Græcum.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fjoVjZ0gB8MC) Lutetia: Typographum Regium, 1554.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Book II, Lecture 7, Chapter 6, D’, 3., a., §329
<sup>2</sup> p. [337](https://books.google.com/books?id=fjoVjZ0gB8MC&dq=%E1%BC%90%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%87%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%AF%CE%B1%20gaudium&pg=PA337#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Comment: I would add that Greek tends to favor compound words far more than Latin, so it is not surprising that an idiomatic Latin expression takes up several words.

Comment: I think Aquinas used an Arabic-derived translation of Aristotle. So he would not have translated this word directly from Greek.